# Python remove all numbers from a list

Tags: python-2.7, list, int

I have a list of unicode elements and I'm trying to remove all integer numbers from It. 
My code is:

```
List = [u'123', u'hello', u'zara', u'45.3', u'pluto']

for el in List:
   if isinistance(el, int):
      List.remove(el)
```

The code doesn't work, It give me the same list with u'123' include.
What i need is this:

```
List = [ u'hello', u'zara', u'45.3', u'pluto']
```

Can somebody hel me?

Answer (score 2):

You list consists of unicode strings which are no instances of `int` obviously. You can try converting them to `int` in a helper function and use this as a condition to remove them/ to construct a new list.

```
def repr_int(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

original_list = [u'123', u'hello', u'zara', u'45.3', u'pluto']

list_with_removed_ints = [elem for elem in original_list if not repr_int(elem)]
```

Comment: you can simply `list_with_removed = filter(repr_int, original_list)`

Comment: Yes, sure! Some style guides discourage the use of this functional style though and encourage using list comprehensions instead. Since I do like Haskell, `filter` would be my choice too, but I try to adhere to the style guides whenever possible.