# How to return all items from a list that dont start with a digit?

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list that consists of both words and digits. Lets say:

```
list1 = ['1','100', 'Stack', 'over','flow']
```

From this list I would like to filter all the digits and keep the words. I have imported re and found the re code for it, namely:

```
[^0-9]
```

However, I am not sure how to implement this so that I get a list like below.

```
result = ['Stack', 'over', 'flow']
```

Comment: Why does it have to be regex? Why not [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)?

Comment: Did you try anything? List comprehension? `filter`?

Comment: See [Python remove all numbers from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280990/python-remove-all-numbers-from-a-list) and [How to remove all integer values from a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159155/how-to-remove-all-integer-values-from-a-list-in-python).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to regex, use [`isdigit()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm) :

```
list1 = ['1','100', 'Stack', 'over','flow']
print([i for i in list1 if not i.isdigit()])
```

returns :

```
['Stack', 'over', 'flow']
```

Answer (score 2):

use `list-comprehension` and string method `isdigit`:

```
[elem for elem in list1 if not elem.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite nicely with list comprehension:

```
list1 = ['1','100', 'Stack', 'over','flow']
list2 = [i for i in list1 if not i.isdigit()]
```

If, for whatever reason, you did want to use regex to do this (maybe you have more complex filtering criteria), you could do it using something like this:

```
import re

list1 = ['1','100', 'Stack', 'over','flow']
list2 = [i for i in list1 if re.fullmatch('[^0-9]+', i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` + `lambda`:

```
list(filter(lambda x: not x.isdigit(), list1))
# ['Stack', 'over', 'flow']
```

Answer (score 0):

Like other answers suggested, you don't really need Regexes, but they can be more flexible if your requirements change in the future. For example.

```
from re import match
list1 = ['1','100', 'Stack', 'over','flow']
result = list(filter(lambda el: match(r'^[^0-9]*$', el), list1))
```

- `^`: start of the string
- `[...]`: character group
- `^`: negates the character group
- `0-9`: digits 0-9 (you could use `\d` as well)
- `*`: zero or more times
- `$`: end of the string

If you want all elements that don't start with a number, use `^[^0-9].*` where `.` is any character.

Comment: This is what I was looking for; thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exact pattern of your list element but this code should work for given example

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("([A-Za-z])")

list1 = ['1','100', 'Stack', 'over','flow']
result = []

for x in list1: 
    check = pattern.match(x)
    if check is not None:
        result.append(x)
print (result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#python 3
olist = list(filter(lambda s: s.isalpha() , list1))
<br>print(olist) # ['Stack', 'over', 'flow']

#python2
olist = filter(lambda s:s.isalpha(), list1) 
<br>print olist # ['Stack', 'over', 'flow']
```